# How do I use the pyplot module of matplotlib in anaconda/Spyder?

Tags: python, macos, matplotlib

I keep getting this error:

```
 runfile('/Users/janani/Documents/TextbooksandResources/ComputationalPhysics/Projects/Summer 2016/Simple Pendulm Problem/simplependulum2.py', wdir='/Users/janani/Downloads')
    Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-9-c2ed32828571>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/Users/janani/Documents/TextbooksandResources/Computational Physics/Projects/Summer 2016/Simple Pendulm Problem/simplependulum2.py', wdir='/Users/janani/Downloads')

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 714, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/spyderlib/widgets/externalshell/sitecustomize.py", line 81, in execfile
    builtins.execfile(filename, *where)

  File "/Users/janani/Documents/TextbooksandResources/Computational Physics/Projects/Summer 2016/Simple Pendulm Problem/simplependulum2.py", line 12, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.colorbar

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/colorbar.py", line 34, in <module>
    import matplotlib.collections as collections

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/collections.py", line 27, in <module>
    import matplotlib.backend_bases as backend_bases

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 56, in <module>
    import matplotlib.textpath as textpath

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/textpath.py", line 22, in <module>
    from matplotlib.mathtext import MathTextParser

  File "/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/mathtext.py", line 63, in <module>
    import matplotlib._png as _png

    ImportError: dlopen(/Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so, 2): Library not loaded: @loader_path/../../../libpng15.15.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/janani/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/matplotlib/_png.so
  Reason: image not found
```

I tried upgrading matplotlib but it said that it's already upgraded (for Python 2.7).

I have Mac OSX 10.9.5

Edit:
I can import matplot lib, but I can't use pyplot.
So `import matplotlib as mpl` doesn't give an error but `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` brings the above error

Comment: Are you able to import matplotlib from a python terminal?

Comment: No I'm not, it comes up with the same error.